# Zurb Orbit Slider does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, orbit

So here we are: http://greeceinsiders.com/VLASIOS/offcanvas/studio.html

I followed the instructions for having the orbit slider in a page but this one doesnt seem to be working. I read from other users that they experience similar problems. Can anyone help?

```
<ul data-orbit class="orbit-slides-container">
  <li data-orbit-slide="1">
    <img src="images/studio/1.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li data-orbit-slide="2">
    <img src="images/studio/2.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
  <li data-orbit-slide="3">
    <img src="images/studio/3.jpg" />
    <div class="orbit-caption">...</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and at the end of the closing body tag I include the javascripts:

```
<!-- Check for Zepto support, load jQuery if necessary -->
<script>
  document.write('<script src=/javascripts/vendor/'
    + ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery')
    + '.js><\/script>');
</script>




    <!-- Included JS Files -->
    <script src="javascripts/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.reveal.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.orbit.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.forms.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.tooltips.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.alerts.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.buttons.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.accordion.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.navigation.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.mediaQueryToggle.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/jquery.offcanvas.js"></script>
      <script src="javascripts/foundation/app.js"></script>



    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>


        <!-- Orbit Bullet Slide Indicator -->
        <ol class="orbit-bullets">
          <li data-orbit-slide-number="1"></li>
          <li data-orbit-slide-number="2" class="active"></li>
          <li data-orbit-slide-number="3"></li>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Zepto uploaded to your server or it's in the wrong file location. You're getting the following NOT FOUND error: http://greeceinsiders.com/javascripts/vendor/zepto.js

Comment: this is the only error I get: 

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'foundation' studio.html:140
(anonymous function)

any idea why?